# When I write to a text file in python 3.5.1 the text file is blank

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing to a text file but the final content is blank. Can anyone help.

```
def main():
    types = input('What is the device type? Phone or Tablet')
    save = open('type.txt', 'w')
    save.write(types)
    save.close
    if types == 'phone':
        import Type1
    elif types == 'tablet':
        import Type2
    else:
        main()

main()
```

I've tried what I could but I'm not an expert on python.

Comment: `save.close()` should close this problem

Comment: Note that using the context manager `with open(...) as save:` would have `save`d (stop giggling at the back) you from this.

Answer (score 3):

In Python every method call is with parentheses. Just use `save.close()`.

Answer (score 3):

The save.close part should be the culprit here. Try changing it to:

```
save.close()
```

It can be a hard bug to catch because this won't cause an exception. The interpreter will silently return a value such as:

```
<built-in method close of _io.TextIOWrapper object at 0x003E7CB0>
```

Try entering in the contents of main() line-by-line interactively to see an example if you'd like.

The following would be even better, as you wouldn't have to call the close method yourself:

```
with open('type.txt', 'w') as save:
    save.write(types)
```